# Does this code loop through multiple rows returned by MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

I have the PHP code below. It is supposed to select up to ten rows from the database and take that information and input it in arrays defined above to be looped through later on in the code and printed on the page. There are three rows it is supposed to select but it is only selecting the latest one. Any idea why?

```
//create arrays for storing each tests information
$subject = array();
$tag = array();
$title = array();
$creator = array();
$creation_date = array();
$test_type = array();
$test_id = array();

$q = "SELECT test_id, title, subject, type, creation_date FROM tests WHERE user_id='$user_id' LIMIT 10"; //select first ten of users tests
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0) //if the query ran correctly and the test details were gathered from the database
{
    $i = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $test_id[] = $row['test_id'];
        $test_type[] = $row['type'];
        $creation_date[] = $row['creation_date'];
        $creator[] = $user_id;
        $title[] = $row['title'];
        $subject[] = $row['subject'];

        $q = "SELECT tag_id FROM test_tags WHERE test_id='$test_id[$i]'"; //selects tags for test
        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0) //if the query ran correctly and the tag_ids were gathered from the database
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $thisTag = $row['tag_id'];

                $q = "SELECT name FROM tags WHERE tag_id='$thisTag' LIMIT 1"; //selects tag name
                $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0)//if the query ran correctly and the tags were gathered from the database
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $tag[$i][] = $row['name'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}//end of SELECT if
```

Comment: Appropriately indent your code or bust.

Comment: Fixed it, waiting for peer review

Comment: Are you sure you're selecting the 3 rows needed? If you run the same query on phpMyAdmin (as example) does it return what you want it to return? I'm just asking because it's quite often to see people looking for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: @coreyward yeah, sorry about that. I really do need to get into the habit of doing that. @mazzzzz thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it looks like your doing is a many to many database.  (meaning you have many posts connected to many tags).
Two things, you are using the same row variable throughout the nested queries, and you are using the same result variable.  both should be avoided.  Try the code below, and tell me how it works.

```
<?php
//create arrays for storing each tests information
$subject = array();
$tag = array();
$title = array();
$creator = array();
$creation_date = array();
$test_type = array();
$test_id = array();

$q = "SELECT test_id, title, subject, type, creation_date FROM tests WHERE user_id='$user_id' LIMIT 10"; //select first ten of users tests
$r1 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0) //if the query ran correctly and the test details were gathered from the database
{
    $i = 0;

    while($orow = mysqli_fetch_array($r1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $test_id[] = $orow['test_id'];
        $test_type[] = $orow['type'];
        $creation_date[] = $orow['creation_date'];
        $creator[] = $user_id;
        $title[] = $orow['title'];
        $subject[] = $orow['subject'];

        $q = "SELECT tag_id FROM test_tags WHERE test_id='{$test_id[$i]}'"; //selects tags for test
        $r2 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0) //if the query ran correctly and the tag_ids were gathered from the database
        {
            while($irow = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $thisTag = $irow['tag_id'];

                $q = "SELECT name FROM tags WHERE tag_id='{$thisTag}' LIMIT 1"; //selects tag name
                $r3 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0)//if the query ran correctly and the tags were gathered from the database
                {
                    while($iirow = mysqli_fetch_array($r3, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $tag[$i][] = $iirow['name'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}//end of SELECT if
?>
```